# Unable to adb push on Samsung S4

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s-4, file-system

I absolutely can't push to /system/app/ using adb
on a rooted S4 with rw remounted filesystem.

adb says:
Read-only file system

Mounts:

```
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0

/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
```

Nothing helps! What is wrong? I can't use adb root, because it gives me:

```
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

I have following permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx root     root              1971-01-17 12:49 /system
drwxrwxrwx root     root              1971-01-17 12:49 /system/app
drwxrwxrwx root     system            2014-10-28 14:15 /data
drwxrwxrwx shell    system            2014-10-28 15:02 /data/app
```

Now I just installed Cyanogenmod, but it doesn
t work either.

Answer (score 3):

If the ADB daemon is not running in root mode, you cannot push to `/system/app` even with `/system` mounted read-write, due to not be given the permission. As you correctly pointed out, `adb root` is no option on non-development-devices ("adbd cannot run as root in production builds").

To fix this up, take a look at chainfire's [adb Insecure](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd). This app requires root (a condition your device obviously meets), and (temporarily) patches the ADB daemon to run in root mode. So with "insecure mode" enabled, you should be able to push to `/system/app`.

Alternatively, push to e.g. `/data/local`, then login to the device with `adb shell`, execute `su` to switch to root-mode, and move the files (`mv /data/local/whatever.apk /system/app`) while `/system` is mounted read-write.

Answer (score 1):

See the following instructions:

1. Push the `.apk` to SD card using:

   ```
   adb push (filename) /sdcard/
   ```
2. Install [Terminal Emulator for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) or [Connectbot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot&hl=en) from Play Store. (You may write your own too.)
3. Launch the terminal and type `su`;
4. If superuser permission is granted then mount `/system` for read/write by the command:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /system
   ```
5. Copy your `.apk` to `/system/app` using:

   ```
   cp /sdcard/(filename) /system/app/
   ```
6. Make `/system` read only:

   ```
   mount -o remount,ro /system
   ```

And you are done!